# They satisfy the equation but they aren't independent events

Tags: probability

I'm a little bit confused about independence of events. I've been reading about it,and doing some problems in order to get ready for my exam, but I still can't think of an example.
The problem is to find a sample space with three events A,B,C that satisfy $$ P(A\cap B\cap C)=P(A)P(B)P(C) $$ but that aren't independent.

But if they satisfy the equation, aren't they supposed to be independent? Is there a book I can read about it?

Comment: 'But if they satisfy the equation, aren't they supposed to satisfy the equation' ????? You're saying exactly the same thing

Comment: Yes, sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three events $A$, $B$, $C$ are independent if$$ P(A\cap B\cap C)=P(A)P(B)P(C) $$ **and if** $$ P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B),\quad P(B\cap C)=P(B)P(C),\quad P(A\cap C)=P(A)P(C).$$ Thus you are asked to find $A$, $B$, $C$ such that the first condition holds but at least one of the others fail.

Note that if $P(C)=0$ and $P(A\cap B)\ne P(A)P(B)$, you are done. To be more ambitious, you could try to find a counterexample where $P(A)P(B)P(C)\ne0$.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think the problem as stated is well defined. The definition of independence is that the probability of the joint event is the product of the probabilities of the individual events.

Comment: Old question, but this statement needs correction.  The definition of independence of events $A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n$ is that *every subset of events*, including but not limited to the entire set of events themselves, satisfies that the probability of their intersection is equal to the product of their probabilities.  In the case of four events $A,B,C,D$ that would mean that $\Pr(A\cap B\cap C\cap D)=\Pr(A)\Pr(B)\Pr(C)\Pr(D)$ in addition to $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A)\Pr(B)$ and $\Pr(A\cap C)=\Pr(A)\Pr(C)$ as well as $\Pr(A\cap B\cap C)=\Pr(A)\Pr(B)\Pr(C)$ and so on...